# How can I prove the identity $\dfrac{1}{1+\sin(x)}\equiv \dfrac{\sec^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\left(\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+1\right)^2}$

Tags: trigonometry

I have to prove by working on the left hand side of the equation that

$$\dfrac{1}{1+\sin(x)}\equiv \dfrac{\sec^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\left(\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+1\right)^2}$$
However I just cant seem to get it, I first started by rewriting the denominator using sin half angle formula

$$\frac{1}{1+2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2})}=\frac{1}{\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})+\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})+2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2})}$$

Then by simplifying further
$$=\dfrac{1}{(\sin(\frac{x}{2})+\cos(\frac{x}{2}))^2}$$
However I'm stumped here and do not know how to proceed, I even took an alternate path and tried rationalizing the fraction as such

$$\frac{1}{1+\sin(x)}*\frac{1-\sin(x)}{1-\sin(x)}=\frac{1-\sin(x)}{(1-\sin(x))^2}$$
And applying $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$
$$=\frac{1-\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$$
$$=\sec^2(x)*(1-\sin(x))$$

But again I get stuck, is there some identity I am forgetting to implement or some other method to approach the left hand side with?

Comment: Do you **have to** work on the left hand side of the equation? That seems a weird requirement...Can't you begin by working your way through the right hand side?

Comment: @DonAntonio I have to work on the left hand side because the original question was on finding $\int{\dfrac{1}{sin(x)+1}}\equiv -\dfrac{2}{\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+1}+C$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $$\dfrac{\sec\dfrac x2}{\tan\dfrac x2+1}\equiv\dfrac1{\sin\dfrac x2+\cos\dfrac x2}$$

Now you have already identified $$\left(\sin\dfrac x2+\cos\dfrac x2\right)^2=?$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, use half angle theorems: $$\sin(x) \equiv \frac{2\tan(x/2)}{1+\tan^2(x/2)} $$

Answer (score 1):

We can express any value trigonometric ratio of a given angle $2\theta$ in terms of the tangent of half that angle. For example:

$$\sin2\theta\equiv\frac{2\tan\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}$$
$$\cos2\theta\equiv\frac{1-\tan^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}$$
$$\tan2\theta\equiv\frac{2\tan\theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}$$
As an aside, this is useful in integration. So, you may want to use the first identity given to prove your identity.